# Transforming web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

i am pretty new this 
I would like to transform web.config when i searched on the web i found SlowCheetah , But i am
not able to transform the setting since i can find any common attribute with value
below is the one i want to transform

```
<smtp deliveryMethod="Network" >
      <network host="xxx" userName="xxxx" password="xxx" port="xxx" enableSsl="xxx" defaultCredentials="false" />
  </smtp>
```

This what i want to transform it into

```
<smtp deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory" from="xxxxx">
    <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="C:\" />
  </smtp>
```

Thank u in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following transform.

```
<smtp deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory" from="xxxxx" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes">
    <network xdt:Transform="Remove" />
    <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="C:\" xdt:Transform="Insert" />
</smtp>
```

You can find more information about all the transform capabilities on msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx